# React: check if props undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do some things in componentDidUpdate if a prop is undefined, however, I can't because I just get the error *Cannot read property 'serial' of undefined*. Is there a way to solve this?

This is what I tired, but it doesn't work - I get the error:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (typeof this.props.location.state.serial == "undefined"){
const database = db.ref().child("Devices/" + prevProps.location.state.serial);
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you see when you log `prevProps.location.state`?

Comment: You can avoid the error with "optional chaining": `this.props.location?.state?.serial` if it's alright in your case to `location.state` being completely `undefined`

Comment: @justDan I get the previous prop, that part works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should make a test on the `location` and the `location.state` objects because they may be `undefined` because this method is called immediately after any update in the state or in the props from the parent component. you can see [the Official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate). Rather you should do this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location && this.props.location.state &&  typeof this.props.location.state.serial === "undefined"){
const database = db.ref().child("Devices/" + prevProps.location.state.serial);
...
```

Or if you'd like to take advantage of new EcmaScript syntax [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (typeof this.props.location?.state?.serial === "undefined"){
const database = db.ref().child("Devices/" + prevProps.location.state.serial);
...
```